# Send Push Notification from Web Page(Admin Panel) to Android Phones using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, web, push-notification, firebase-notifications

I want to send push notification using firebase from my admin panel web page to the android phones registered in firebase database. I have tried sending notifications using PHP and mySQL but want to use firebase only to send notification. I have also tried sending notification from firebase console to android devices. But I want to use the firebase API to send notification from web to android devices.

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: yes I did. With firebase you need to register the device. You will get API link that you will use both on your android device and web pannel. It will act as a third party, you will hit that from your web console with the notification data and that will send the notification to mobile device

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-push-notifications-to-a-web-app-with-firebase-528a702e13e1/
the api he is hitting from postman, you need to hit the same APi with your web app and the notification will be sent to mobile

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Notification is a panel in the Firebase Console, where you can send messages to specific devices, device groups, topics and audiences. It cannot send messages to Web users (yet). There is no public API for Firebase Notifications.

There is an API for Firebase Cloud Messaging, on top of which Notifications is built. FCM support most ways of sending messages: specific devices, device groups and topics. It also supports sending to all platforms: iOS, Android and Web.

But sending messages to devices through FCM always requires that you specify the FCM Server Key. As its name implies, this key should only be used on trusted processes. The most common way to run a trusted process is to run it on your app server (for example using PHP code that runs on a hosted server). But you can also run it on your own machine. Firebase recently released Cloud Functions for Firebase, which allows you to run JavaScript functions on Google's hardware. [Sending FCM messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens) is one of the documented use-cases for Cloud Functions for Firebase.

Comment: I am using local server(wamp) to run php scripts. The problem is the IP of the network does not remain fixed due to which I am unable to send tokens from mobile to local server and then to firebase. Can you please suggest me the solution or provide me the link to send notifications from my website to the android devices.

Comment: Waiting for your reply.